# Improve speed of MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT:

I reworked the query as follows:

```
SELECT
  a.title, count(*),at.search_code
FROM 
  `qitz3_attributes_type` at
left join
  qitz3_attributes a
on 
  a.attribute_type_id = at.id
left join
  qitz3_attributes_property ap
on
  ap.attribute_id = a.id
left join
  qitz3_helloworld h
on
  h.id = ap.property_id
where 
  at.id in (1,2,8,9,11)
and 
  a.search_filter = 1
and
  h.area=506
and 
  h.expiry_date >= '2013-02-20 13:28:04' 
group by 
  a.title
order by search_code
```

This seems much faster but I am still getting a using temporary and using filesort on the explain...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  at  range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   NULL    5   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  a   ref PRIMARY,Attribute type ID,Search filter,Attribute ...   Attribute type ID   4   password.at.id  6   Using where
1   SIMPLE  ap  ref Property ID,Attribute ID,Attribute Property Attribute Property  4   password.a.id   142 Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  h   eq_ref  PRIMARY,Area indexes,Expiry date    PRIMARY 4   password.ap.property_id 1   Using where
```

ENDEDIT

I am working on a search component for a site I am developing and while it is all working there are a couple of queries that I would like to see running a touch faster.

In order to populate a set of search filters (display the count of the number of properties that have each facility or are of a particular type) I am using the following two queries. The first will get a list of IDs that I then plug into the second query as follows:

Based on the following info can anyone suggest a more efficient way to do this? I would really like to speed the first query up as it seems a little slow compared to the others.

Is 150ms actually that slow? 15ms would be better...

Thanks,

Adam

Query 1 (takes around 150ms):

```
  SELECT h.id, h.parent_id, h.level, h.title as property_title, h.area, h.region, h.department, h.city, 
  LEFT(h.description, 250) as description, h.thumbnail, h.occupancy, h.swimming, g.path, (single_bedrooms + double_bedrooms + triple_bedrooms + quad_bedrooms + twin_bedrooms) as bedrooms, c.title as location_title, ( select min(tariff) 
  from qitz3_tariffs 
  where id = h.id ) as price, e.title as tariff_based_on, f.title as base_currency, a.title as property_type, a2.title as accommodation_type, ( select count(*) 
  from qitz3_reviews 
  where property_id = h.id 
  group by h.id ) as reviews 
  FROM qitz3_classifications c 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_helloworld h 
  on c.id = h.area 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_property ap 
  ON ap.property_id = h.id 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_type at 
  ON at.id = ap.attribute_id 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes a 
  ON a.id = ap.attribute_id 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_property ap2 
  ON ap2.property_id = h.id 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_type at2 
  ON at2.id = ap2.attribute_id 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes a2 
  ON a2.id = ap2.attribute_id 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes e 
  ON e.id = h.tariff_based_on 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes f 
  ON f.id = h.base_currency 
  LEFT JOIN qitz3_classifications g 
  ON g.id = h.city 
  WHERE a.attribute_type_id = 1 
  AND a2.attribute_type_id = 2 
  AND c.id = 506 
  AND h.expiry_date >= '2013-02-20 12:05:13' 
  AND h.id > 1
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY c   const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY h   ref PRIMARY,Area indexes,Expiry date    Area indexes    4   const   615 Using where
1   PRIMARY ap  ref Property ID,Attribute ID    Property ID 4   password.h.id   21  Using where
1   PRIMARY at  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   password.ap.attribute_id    1   Using index
1   PRIMARY a   eq_ref  PRIMARY,Attribute type ID   PRIMARY 4   password.ap.attribute_id    1   Using where
1   PRIMARY ap2 ref Property ID,Attribute ID    Property ID 4   password.ap.property_id 21  Using where
1   PRIMARY at2 eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   password.ap2.attribute_id   1   Using index
1   PRIMARY a2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,Attribute type ID   PRIMARY 4   password.ap2.attribute_id   1   Using where
1   PRIMARY e   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   password.h.tariff_based_on  1   
1   PRIMARY f   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   password.h.base_currency    1   
1   PRIMARY g   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   password.h.city 1   
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  qitz3_reviews   ref Property ID Property ID 4   password.h.id   1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  qitz3_tariffs   ref Property ID Property ID 4   password.h.id   2
```

Query 2 (takes around 30ms):

```
SELECT a.id,count(attribute_id) as count, a.title AS attribute, a.published, at.title as facility_type, at.search_code 
FROM qitz3_attributes AS a 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_type at 
on at.id = a.attribute_type_id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_property ap 
on ap.attribute_id = a.id 
WHERE search_filter = 1 
AND a.published = 1 
AND property_id in (152843,103180,152845,4628,5653,3865,107553,155945,106029,107575,149052,837,104264,98635,98636,98637,98638,3667,106838,3672,157278,155743,157791,157792,151153,151155,100725,106109,157569,157576,107145,150666,103310,5780,3480,102041,154016,3490,154018,932,153518,151991,154041,154042,4288,5832,149451,157646,102094,148444,153822,157407,153839,151536,157393,157395,157428,157429,102236,104770,157378,157380,157381,157382,157383,157654,104768,103746,153683,150175,4618,101050,104942,157229,157230,98515,104771,104944,3612,148721,104212,5307,3432,156676,102706,404,5518,156359,5252,102697,5271,98979,101827,149524,102676,107551,5685,101736,156538,152703,4730,151881,95838,3759,149769,5269,98429,153729,5233,703,5579,98943,157433,3157,155661,107347,147545,147547,5216,106345,156533,93833,158091,96403,3491,968,158195,158196,157580,104148,3030,94686,154725,150582,103027,99062,102462,4384,5634,153874,157974,101669,47,105285,102481,102234,5749,156793,153748,96404,151467,154292,147645,97471,100551,102090,4841,3563,155643,4656,98424,157243,150601,157415,4701,102283,100719,100738,5643,98425,98972,103261,531,3105,98108,150592,5719,150616,157532,3974,3212,157581,97469,97470,149183,157638,149730,102114,156395,153621,102560,102913,94684,5609,157578,98423,98971,102151,146734,150585,104287,155296,104956,94592,102433,147575,156325,106344,101766,107058,106560,103026,157848,98973,4303,5620,149767,150563,4407,104268,97876,156784,156786,149922,701,154317,153821,102480,348,102778,102779,102780,102781,102479,352,103025,98677,5254,98697,3995,156322,100305,98532,3833,5374,150172,151435,102368,102380,157228,103171,147740,152870,103579,3870,104037,103016,4995,105104,157605,5811,955,147643,156648,107802,101502,94685,3569,148755,150293,4122,157013,157297,98676,156794,102848,157635,157640,95717,98980,102764,102777,102782,36,101765,154373,149829,154955,107683,158176,102557,157552,103163,5760,104627,153561,266,151335,151176,147620,147379,3085,155760,106339,151424,106759,5145,104990,97877,155495,5241,156407,156625,3236,152782,96066,147617,3860,4614,3497,147883,158207,102985,104622,101816,157275,149037,4792,149226,3496,101825,102538,150571,105015,97874,157391,158192,102562,155032,5383,102558,104194,156740,101446,147615,5815,107081,155992,97473,148817,945,101751,158074,4249,101792,4532,152828,104316,157319,156071,157508,157510,148836,4745,153823,157942,3859,157442,100017,102555,147629,149272,157845,151256,101481,154735,154737,157652,106232,97991,4660,3309,157597,407,157658,154152,157374,153385,148037,158214,100452)
GROUP BY a.id
```

This query gives a count of the number of properties with each attribute (e.g. Golf, Air conditioning, property type etc). The good thing about this is that only attributes are shown that have properties. So as the user drills down attributes with no properties are not shown. This is basically down to the first query where I get a list of the properties matching a particular set of attributes.

The tables are as follows:

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_attributes`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_attributes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`attribute_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`ordering` int(11) NOT NULL,
`state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`published` int(11) NOT NULL,
`search_filter` bit(1) NOT NULL,
`language_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en-GB',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Attribute type ID` (`attribute_type_id`),
KEY `Search filter` (`search_filter`),
KEY `Published` (`published`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1522 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_attributes_property`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_attributes_property` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Property ID` (`property_id`),
KEY `Attribute ID` (`attribute_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=66261 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_attributes_type`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_attributes_type` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`language_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`field_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`search_code` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`published` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_classifications`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_classifications` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`access` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`published` int(11) NOT NULL,
`longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
`latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_left_right` (`lft`,`rgt`),
KEY `Alias index` (`alias`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=158052 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_helloworld` (Property table)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_helloworld` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`level` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`alias` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`access` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`title` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
`area` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`region` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`department` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`city` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`params` text NOT NULL,
`created_by` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`availability_last_updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`modified_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`lang` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en-GB',
`description` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'The summary and description for this accommodation',
`internal_facilities_other` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`external_facilities_other` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`activities_other` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`location_details` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`getting_there` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`thumbnail` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`occupancy` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`single_bedrooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
`double_bedrooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
`triple_bedrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`quad_bedrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`twin_bedrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`childrens_beds` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`cots` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`extra_beds` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`bathrooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
`toilets` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`swimming` int(11) NOT NULL,
`latitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
`longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
`nearest_town` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`distance_to_coast` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`additional_price_notes` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
`base_currency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`tariff_based_on` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`linen_costs` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
`changeover_day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`published` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`video` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_left_right` (`lft`,`rgt`),
KEY `Area indexes` (`area`,`region`,`department`),
KEY `Expiry date` (`expiry_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=158249 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_reviews`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_reviews` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`review_text` varchar(4000) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
`guest_name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`guest_email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`state` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Property ID` (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=921 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `qitz3_tariffs`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qitz3_tariffs` (
`tariff_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Denotes the property listing ID',
`start_date` date NOT NULL,
`end_date` date NOT NULL,
`tariff` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Price per booking period between the dates specified. dated spec',
PRIMARY KEY (`tariff_id`),
KEY `Property ID` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9267 ;
```

Comment: please pot some sample data

Comment: Can you post the table definitions for the 2 tables used in the subselects (qitz3_tariffs and qitz3_reviews) please?

Comment: I will do. However, did you see my edit? I have written a different query which *is* faster but still results in the dreaded 'using filesort, using temporary' in the explain. See my edit? 

In actual fact, in the initial scenario I posted I only need the ID list and none of the other fields at all!

Comment: Just added additional table definitions.

Comment: You don't have many rows on the qitz3_attributes_type (~34). Possibly MySQL is ignoring the index for the required sort as it is using ~15% of the records and it is quicker to scan the table rather than use the index.

Answer (score 1):

Quick play, but trying to move the subselects out from the field list.

```
SELECT h.id, h.parent_id, h.level, h.title as property_title, h.area, h.region, h.department, h.city, LEFT(h.description, 250) as description, h.thumbnail, h.occupancy, h.swimming, g.path, (single_bedrooms + double_bedrooms + triple_bedrooms + quad_bedrooms + twin_bedrooms) as bedrooms, c.title as location_title, 
Sub1.price, 
e.title as tariff_based_on, f.title as base_currency, a.title as property_type, a2.title as accommodation_type, 
Sub2.reviews 
FROM qitz3_classifications c 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_helloworld h on c.id = h.area 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_property ap ON ap.property_id = h.id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_type at ON at.id = ap.attribute_id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes a ON a.id = ap.attribute_id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_property ap2 ON ap2.property_id = h.id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes_type at2 ON at2.id = ap2.attribute_id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes a2 ON a2.id = ap2.attribute_id 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes e ON e.id = h.tariff_based_on 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_attributes f ON f.id = h.base_currency 
LEFT JOIN qitz3_classifications g ON g.id = h.city 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, MIN(tariff) AS price FROM qitz3_tariffs GROUP BY id) Sub1 ON Sub1.Id = h.id 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT property_id, COUNT(*) AS reviews FROM qitz3_reviews GROUP BY property_id ) as Sub2 ON Sub2.property_id = h.id 
WHERE a.attribute_type_id = 1 
AND a2.attribute_type_id = 2 
AND c.id = 506 
AND h.expiry_date >= '2013-02-20 12:05:13' 
AND h.id > 1
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, in fact seems to make it slower.

Comment: Does it not work (ie, error) or is it slower when working?

Comment: Sorry, it does work but it is slower.

Comment: Fair enough. Might be worth trying it without the subselects. Just to see if they are a real impact on performance. However looking at your original explain again I am surprised it has chosen to use the index on area / region / department. Might be worth trying to add an index to check on expiry date (assuming that there are a significant number of records with an old expiry date). Given MySQL will only use one index on a table try adding one on the area and expiry date columns.

Answer (score 0):

When you need more speed in searching data you should take a look at [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). With this index servers you can index your MySQL-Data and query them.

Its much more faster then MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a lot wrong in your first query:

The first 7 LEFT JOINs should be INNER JOINs. For qitz3_attributes you should consider normalizing the data less aggressively (use multiple columns instead of multiple rows to describe the data.

Comment: Agreed, the query isn't great. It runs slightly faster with INNER JOINS but still over 100ms. I just posted a different query which seems better...

Comment: How could I use multiple columns if I wanted an attribute to have more than one attribute? Agreed, I could add some of the enum types to the property table but I can't see how I could do that for all the attributes